# Populating a field by aggregating other collections

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation, mongoose-populate

I have a user and a ratings collection. Ratings collection has `ratedBy`, `ratedTo` and score.
Now I want to find all users on some criteria and also getting their `ratingAvg`. So the result would look something like the following:

```
[
{_id: 44s5dsdde4e4e55e,name:"bob", email: "bob@gmail.com", ratingAvg: 3, ...},
{_id: 3as5dsdde4e4e55e,name:"alice", email: "alice@gmail.com", ratingAvg: 4, ...}
]
```

I am very new to databases and especially MongoDB. I can find the `ratingAvg` of a particular user by doing this

```
Ratings.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {ratedTo: Mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)}
            }, 
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: "$ratedTo",
                    avgRating: { $avg : "$score" }
                }
            }
        ]);
```

But what I need to do this is to get the users with their fields and `ratingAvg` calculated like above. What I can think of is to find the users separately by `Users.find({field: criteria})` and loop over them and use the above code to find their ratings. Or the solution would be to do a lookup and join users and ratings and then aggregate them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way is to use aggregation with:

- [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#lookup-aggregation) to retrieve all of the matching ratings
- [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html#addfields-aggregation) with [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html#reduce-aggregation) to calculate the sum and count
- `$addFields` with [$divide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/index.html#divide-aggregation) to calculate the average
- [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html#project-aggregation) to remove any temporary fields

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Tvcjtp2bor9)